# Why AWK program FS variable can be specified with -F flag of gawk (or other awk) interpreter/command?

Tags: awk

Why AWK program's FS variable can be specified with -F flag of gawk (or other awk) interpreter/command?

Let me explain, [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is a programming language and [gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) is (one of many) an interpreter for AWK. gawk interpreter/execute/runs the AWK program that given to it. So why the FS (field separator) variable can be specified with gawk's -F flag? I find it kind of unnatural... and how does it technically do that?

Comment: `awk -F: '...' files` is faster to type than `awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} ...' files` or even `awk '...' FS=: files`

Comment: @jhnc : one exception to that rule : if you want the fields to be one byte/character each by blanking `FS`, `awk '…' FS=` is shorter than `awk -F '' '…'`

Answer (score 0):

My best guess as to "why" is as a convenience. FS is probably the most used/manipulated awk variable, so having a short option to set it is helpful

Consider

```bash
awk -F, '...' file.csv
# vs
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} ...' file.csv
```

"How does it technically do that" -- see https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/main.c#n1586

Historically `-F` was [implemented in gawk v1.01](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/awk1.c?h=gawk-1.01#n107) so it would have existed in whatever legacy awk that gawk was based on.

Additionally, the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) mandates `-F`.

Comment: https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk/blob/87b94932e6f12ad16e9fc1af1a7b5b66ae9381e2/main.c#L107

Comment: Even present in oldest version I can find: https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/awk/main.c

Comment: Thanks, could you explain in words, how does it technically do it?

Comment: @Tqau FS is a variable with a predefined initial value. The code takes the value you provide with `-F` and assigns it to that variable, overriding the default: `add_preassign(PRE_ASSIGN_FS, optarg);` / `**FS = argv[0][2];` / `fs = &argv[1][2];`

Answer (score 0):

> So why the FS (field separator) variable can be specified with gawk's
> -F flag?

[`awk` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) claims that

> Command line variable assignment is most useful for dynamically
> assigning values to the variables `AWK` uses to control how input is
> broken into fields and records. It is also useful for controlling
> state if multiple passes are needed over a single data file.

So `-F` comes handy when field separator is not etched in stone, but rather computed dynamically, as `-F` allows you tu use `bash` variable easily, imagine that you was tasked with developing part of `bash` script which should output last field of each line of `file.txt` when using character stored in variable `sep` as separator, then you could do that following way

```
awk -F ${sep} '{print $NF}' file.txt
```

> find it kind of unnatural

This depend on what you have used before, [`cut`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) user which want to get 3rd column from csv file might do that following way

```
cut -d , -f 3 file.csv
```

Comment: cf. `sort -t "$sep" ...`